# How to test multiple commits in a Vuex action

Tags: vuex

I am currently getting to grips with testing in Vuex. I have the following action:

```
import { fetchProfile } from '../api'

export const getProfile = ({ commit }) => {
  return fetchProfile()
   .then(async (profile) => {
    await commit(types.SET_AUTHENTICATED, true)
    await commit(types.SET_PROFILE, profile.user)
   })
}
```

And then the following test:

```
jest.mock('../../src/api')

describe('task actions', () => {
  it('fetchProfile commits user profile returned by api', async () => {
    const profile = { first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Doe' }
    fetchProfile.mockResolvedValue(profile)
    const commit = jest.fn()
    await actions.getProfile({ commit })
    expect(commit).toHaveBeenCalledWith(types.SET_AUTHENTICATED, true)
    expect(commit).toHaveBeenCalledWith('SET_PROFILE', profile)
  })
})
```

This fails with

> "SET_PROFILE"
>   as argument 1, but it was called with
>    "SET_AUTHENTICATED".

If I comment out the second expect, the test passes.

However, how do I test that both commits have happened correctly?
Any help or guidance would be much appreciated

Thanks.

Comment: Ahh. Just added await to both expects and it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added await to the beginning of each expect and it works now!!